# Creating a definition of enum type function outside the class and operator overloading on enum type

Tags: c++, enums

I've got a couple of errors with creating a definition of enum type function outside the class and operator overloading on enum type. I place code below, at the end.

1. Previously I had the error: `'Month' does not name a type` in the function definition outside the class scope:
   `Month Date::int_to_month(int x){ // function body }`
   I've found that `Date::Month` notation is acceptable. My question is, why do we use such notation? Is there any other possibility for doing this?

Now the second problem. I tried to overload `++` operator on enum Month.

The build message I got:

2. `postfix 'Date::Month Date::operator++(Date::Month&)' must take 'int' as an argument`. I dont't understand, where the problem is and why I can't do overloading.

The code:

```
    class Date
    {
    public:
    enum Month{
        jan=1,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec
    };

    Date(int yy, Month mm, int dd);

    Month int_to_month(int x);

    Month operator++(Month& m);

    private:
    int y;
    Month m;
    int d;
    };

    Date::Date(int yy, Month mm, int dd)
     :y(yy),m(mm),d(dd)
    {

    }

    Date::Month Date::int_to_month(int x)
    {
    if (x<jan || dec<x) error("bad month");
    return Month(x);
    }

    Date::Month Date::operator++(Month& m)
    {
    if(m==dec)? jan:Month(m+1);
    return m;
    }
```

PS. Thanks for all answers and effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As `Month` has a scope limited to class `Date` you have to use `Date::Month`. It's worth doing if you have for example another enum called `Month`.
2. `operator++` can be overloaded in four different ways - postfix/prefix, inside/outside class definition. Their typical signatures are:

   ```
   T& T::operator++(); //prefix, inside class definition
   T& operator++(T& a); //prefix, outside class definition
   T T::operator++(int); //postfix, inside class definition
   T operator++(T& a, int); //postfix, outside class defintion
   ```

You can return anything you want but these are typically used return values.

In your example, you overload `operator++` inside of the class but specify an argument for outside of the class version. Inside of the class there are no aguments or `int` and your compiler expects an `int` if you already give it some argument.

Second thing is that the body of your overloaded `operator++` doesn't make much sense. It should increment member `m` but return not incremented value.

```
Date::Month Date::operator++(int)
{
    Month ret = m;

    //if you find ternary operator more readable...
    m = (m == Month::dec ? Month::jan : Month(m + 1)); 

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot with understanding overloading. Now I can see the difference between prefix and postfix definitions, and also I can see my stupid fault with arithmetic if :)

Answer (score 0):

Overloading the postfix version of `operator++` requires a workaround in the language in order to distinguish it from the otherwise identically named prefix version; you have to pass an unused `int` parameter:

```
Month operator++(int);
```

Then there's this line, in which you seem to mix `if` with `?:`. That doesn't make sense:

> ```
> if(m==dec)? jan:Month(m+1);
> ```

Make it:

```
Date::Month Date::operator++(int)
{
    if (m == dec)
    {
        return jan;
    }
    else
    {
        return Month(m + 1);
    }
}
```

This should help you get around the most basic troubles.